# Nesting in UDF [Variable Price & Round to Near 7]

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a pricing function and export it as an Excel Add-In. I'd like the function to have an integer passed into it as an argument, multiply the value by a percentage, and then output that market up value in the form of the nearest number ending with 7.

For example: If I want to mark something that costs $150 up 45% and then round to 7 it would be:

Cost: 150 * 1.45, and then MROUND(X,10)-3

My function thus far is

```
Function MARKUP(c as Integer) as Integer

If c < 20 Then
    MARKUP = (c) * 1.5

ElseIf c < 40 Then
    MARKUP = (c) * 1.4

Else
    MARKUP = (c) * 1.3

End If
End Function
```

---

Obviously I can then pass this value into 'MROUND([cell],10)-3)' to get the markup to the nearest 7, but the end users will not be people who are inclined to handle this.

I'd like this to be a 1-step process if possible. I can't picture how to nest the MROUND() function into the custom MARKUP() function.

---

I'm imagining the psuedo-code would be similar to:

```
    Function MARKUP(c as Integer) as Integer

If c < 20 Then
    MARKUP = (c) * 1.5

ElseIf c < 40 Then
    MARKUP = (c) * 1.4

Else
    MARKUP = (c) * 1.3

End If

MARKUP = (MROUND(C,10)-3) [???]

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the `WorksheetFunction` from VBA like so:

```
MARKUP = Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound(c * 1.5, 10) - 3
```

---

`Select Case` is my preferred method when analyzing one variable (`c`). Also, `c as Long` is probably the safer route compared to `integer` (as suggested by @QHarr)

```
Function MARKUP(c As Long) As Integer

Select Case c
    Case c < 20
        MARKUP = Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound(c * 1.5, 10) - 3
    Case c < 40
        MARKUP = Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound(c * 1.4, 10) - 3
    Case Else
        MARKUP = Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound(c * 1.3, 10) - 3
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: If the idea of the function is to mark UP shouldn't you use CEILING rather than MROUND?

Comment: Thanks much! I'm not super well-versed in VBA and that WorksheetFunction is EXACTLY what I was looking for!